# How to delete/edit one in series of reoccuring events

Tags: calendar

Is there a way to delete or edit just one event in a series of reoccuring events?

Htc Desire

Kernel Version 2.6.32.15-gf5a501c

Software Number Version 2.29.405.2

Comment: please point out phone model and android version

Comment: phone software specifics added

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you choose the particular event you want to edit or delete you are given 3 options (at least on my Droid 1 I am):

> 1. **Change only this event**
> 2. Change all events in the series
> 3. Change this and all future events

Choose #1 to change just that one event in the series.

Comment: this option is not available in "later" versions of android.